# installing pip3 (for python3) on ubuntu 16.04 LTS using a proxy

Tags: apt, package-management, python, python3, pip

I have tried entering:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

The error I get is:

```
$ sudo apt install python3-pip  
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
The following additional packages will be installed:
    libexpat1-dev libpython3-dev libpython3.5-dev python-pip-whl python3-dev python3-wheel python3.5-dev 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
    libexpat1-dev libpython3-dev libpython3.5-dev python-pip-whl python3-dev python3-pip python3-wheel python3.5-dev 0 to upgrade, 8 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade. 
Need to get 1,219 kB/39.1 MB of archives. 
After this operation, 56.8 MB of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y 
Ign:1 au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 python-pip-whl all 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.1 
Ign:2 au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 python3-pip all 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.1 
Err:1 au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 python-pip-whl all 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.1
    404  Not Found 
Err:2 au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 python3-pip all 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.1
    404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-pip/python-pip-whl_8.1.1-2ubuntu0.1_all.deb 
    404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-pip/python3-pip_8.1.1-2ubuntu0.1_all.deb
    404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I believe we have bypassed the proxy, so I'm not sure why I'm getting '404 file not found'.

Comment: Try again running `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Works from home fine, but I have Linux machines at the school I teach at, which have a proxy which I thought we had bypassed for ubuntu.com, but looks like I haven't somehow...

Comment: So this has nothing to do with Ubuntu but your network configuration then.

Answer (score 205):

The first procedure you followed is correct

```sh
sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
```

But before installing try to update using command

```sh
sudo apt-get update
```

If first did not work then you can also do this using **curl**

```sh
curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
python3 get-pip.py --user
```

Then to verify installation try

```sh
pip3 --help
```

For checking version :

```sh
pip3 --version
```

Comment: Thank you! But it needed: "pip3 --help"

Comment: `curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python`

Comment: Interesting! Why do you need the 'sudo apt-get update' to install pip3? seems rather unexpected to me.

Comment: This does not work for pip3, it installs pip2 script which python3 can't run.

Comment: `curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3` for Python 3 ;)

Comment: working with "sudo python get-pip.py" for me. Thanks!

Comment: In case of error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig'` install the `python3-distutils` first. Like this `apt install python3-distutils`

Comment: thank you it works on windows 10 WSL

Answer (score 2):

I fixed such problem by changing Server in "Software & Updates" -> Download from:
there I chose different address and  404 disappeared.

Comment: what address did you choose? please add more details

Answer (score 2):

what worked for me

```
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py >>setup.py
python3 setup.py
```