# Is it possible to avoid setting path manually for python package executables?

Tags: apt, python, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed python 3 and `pip3` into in Windows System for Linux shell that uses Ubuntu, but it appears I have to find and specify `site-packages` or `$HOME/.local/bin` directory manually if I want to run any python package executables.

The package I want to use is [cheat](https://github.com/chrisallenlane/cheat), but the problem is the same for any other package.

My chain of commands was:

1. install WSL - Ubuntu 18.04
2. `sudo apt-get update` (because `sudo apt-get install pip3` [will not work
   on fresh installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778052/installing-pip3-for-python3-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-using-a-proxy))
3. `sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip` (installs python too) - edited
4. `sudo pip3 install cheat`
5. `cheat` not recognised as a command, while `python3` runs fine from
   `/usr/bin/python3`
6. find locations where `cheat` is found, they are:

   ```
   $HOME/.local/bin/cheat 
   $HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cheat
   ```
7. When I add any of these directories to path, I'm able to run python executables, `cheat ls` works.

Is there something I can change in the installation process so that I mustn't search for directories and add them manually to path?

Comment: I don't understand: `~/.local/bin` is where pip usually installs executables for user-installation. You only need to know that once, there's no need to search for the location again and again.

Comment: @muru - I'm saying that on a bare linux installation a user would have to search for `~/.local/bin` to find out where the executable is, if he has no prior knowledge of pip behaviour. On Windows executables work right after pip install, no searching needed.

Comment: @muru - also not clear why `sudo pip3 install cheat` still installs to a user home directory.

Comment: all the more reason to be aware of the behavior of tools that download programs from the internet. As for sudo pip, I assumed you ran one command and pasted another here, because sudo pip installs binaries to `/usr/local/bin`, which is in PATH.

Comment: @muru - do you care to post your last comment as an answer? This is really the case after I repeted my steps: `sudo` does install at `/usr/local/bin/cheat` and local directories installation  emerges when doing pip with no `sudo`.

Comment: I know with some modules you can do `python -m modulename`. That'll search for modules in their respective paths. But depends on how module is built.

Comment: @ Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy `python -m` is a good idea, I sometimes invoke `pytest` like this to persist a start folder, but for cheat specifically it is doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

@muru provided proper diagnostics: the issue with local directories arises only when running `pip3 install cheat`.

When running `sudo pip3 install cheat` the package executable installs to `/usr/local/bin/` which is on path.

For the rest of the question "Why did my local version of python package install to a directory which is not in path", the overall answer is close to "You have to know your system and folder structure", which equates to "Put `~/.local/bin/`on path.

So reiterating to conclude - if you are installing a package with `pip` and you are not in sudo mode, you have to add `~/.local/bin/` to path to make package executable run.